# Ravendb Orderby and Last

Tags: ravendb

How do I get this query to work in RavenDB:

```
using (var session = _store.OpenSession(databasename))
{
  return session.Query<MyDataClass>().OrderBy(x => x.DateTime).LastOrDefault();
}
```

I have been struggling with Indexes and not figuring them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
return session.Query<MyDataClass>().OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I tried this but had a different error and I was changing too much a one time in my code. Need more unit testing. Thanks again.